# IF statement in Excel woes

Tags: microsoft-excel

In Excel i need a formula for the following: If the end date on sheet 2 cell A1 is 3 days later than the start date on this sheet cell a2, then the cell must turn red.

Please help!

Comment: =$A$1-Sheet1!$A$2>3

Comment: Should be >= to pick up a date that is exactly 3 days later.

Answer (score 0):

Enter this formula into conditional formating.

> =IF(A1<(A2-3),TRUE,FALSE)

Comment: @rajeev has it right